Using ROS Driver as Hardware Interface for ros2_control
I am looking to use ros2_control with my robot and have found a suitable driver from Github that works with my motor controller (https://github.com/DoanNguyenTrong/roboteq_controller_ros/tree/galactic-devel). My question now is what the correct way would be to make this Driver work with a Hardware Interface / as a Hardware Interface. I know the Driver is not a Hardware Interface, but am looking for someone with expertise regarding Hardware Interfaces etc.
<xacro:unless value="$(arg sim_mode)">
        <ros2_control name="RoboteqInterface" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>roboteq_controller/RoboteqDriver</plugin>
                <param name="wheel_circumference_">0.6594</param>
                <param name="track_width_">.6223</param>
                <param name="max_rpm_">100.0</param>
                <param name="frequency_">50</param>
                <param name="serial_port_">/dev/ttyACM0</param>
                <param name="baudrate_">115200</param>
                <param name="closed_loop_">false</param>
                <param name="diff_drive_mode_">true</param>
                <param name="cmd_vel_topic_">/cmd_vel</param>            
            </hardware>
            <joint name="Left_motor_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="Right_motor_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>
    </xacro:unless>

^
Example code that doesn't work.

You will have to write a new hardware component, where you add the code from the repository you've linked.
Have a look at this step-by-step guide on how to write hardware components, or the demos with simple examples.

Just to clarify, do you mean writing a new hardware component and linking to the driver (so running the driver and hardware component simultaneously) OR writing a new hardware component and adding the code from the repository so there is no need to start the driver seperately anymore (only running the new hardware component)?
Thanks in advance.

The "driver" is a simple node with the necessary communication to the hardware, and as far as I've seen it is not encapsulated in a useful class to be included in your component. Implement this directly in the hardware component.
Just to mention, the hardware components typically do not spawn a node hence you can't use the parameter structure directly. See the demos, how to add the parameter parsing as you proposed in the ros2_control tag of your initial question.
